# Posting new offers/features in my existing Android app in Google console without uploading new apk file

Tags: android

I am new in Android. How some apps/games updating their apps/games like different offers each day without uploading a new update file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you can look into Firebase's push notifications. It allows pretty powerful targetted marketing. You can get an overview here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb2GZ3Bh4p8

For more information on its features, refer its documantation: https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: Thanks for fast reply! however is there any way i can add some offers/futures in app but not on notification without publish new apk?

Comment: What do you mean not on notification. As in, user will be notified when she opens the app again or something?